# Create partial index for postgresql jsonb field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to add a partial index to postgresql jsonb column. The jsonb column is named: **email_provider**. I have tried adding a partial index on the column as shown below but it throws different error like this **PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "email_povider" does not exist** and at other times it raises the error: **PG::AmbiguousFunction: ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown -> unknown**

The partial index in the **rails-5** migration looks like this:

```
add_index  :accounts, :name, name:  "index_accounts_on_email_provider_kind", using: :gin, where: "('email_provider' -> 'sparkpost' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.sparkpost.com') AND ('email_povider' -> 'amazon ses' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.awses.com')"
```

The json for the email_provider column looks like this:

```
 {
   "email_provider": {
     "sparkpost": {
        "smtp_host": "www.sparkpost.com",
        "smtp_port": ""
      },
      "aws ses": {
        "smtp_host": "www.amazon/ses.com ",
        "smtp_port": " ",
        "username": " ",
        "password": " "
      }
  }
}
```

The table looks like this:

```
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
   def change
      create_table :accounts do |t|
        t.string :name, null: false
        t.jsonb :email_provider, null: false
        t.jsonb :social_account, default: '[]', null: false
        t.timestamps
   end
      add_index  :accounts, :name, name: "index_accounts_on_email_provider_kind", using: :gin, where: "('email_provider' -> 'sparkpost' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.sparkpost.com') AND ('email_povider' -> 'amazon ses' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.awses.com')"

      add_index  :accounts, :name, name: "index_accounts_on_social_account_type", using: :gin, where: " 'social_account' @> [{'type': 'facebook'}] AND 'social_account' @> [{'type': 'twitter'}]"
   end
end
```

**Update**

Based on slight adjustment to the accepted answer below, the code I am using to create **btree** not **gin** index in rails activerecord is shown below. It creates a btree index because we are using the **name column which is of string datatype** and not jsonb as described [here](http://blog.heapanalytics.com/speeding-up-postgresql-queries-with-partial-indexes/) :

```
add_index :accounts, :name, name:  "index_accounts_on_name_email_provider", where: "email_provider -> 'sparkpost' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.sparkpost.com' AND email_provider -> 'amazon ses' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.awses.com' "

add_index  :accounts, :name, name: "index_accounts_on_name_social_account", where: " social_account @> '[{\"type\": \"facebook\"}]'::jsonb AND social_account @> '[{\"type\": \"twitter\"}]'::jsonb"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need something like that:

```
add_index :accounts, :email_provider, name:  "index_accounts_on_email_provider_kind", using: :gin, where: "(email_provider -> 'email_provider' -> 'sparkpost' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.sparkpost.com') AND (email_provider -> 'email_povider' -> 'amazon ses' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.awses.com')"
```

I've changed the second argument of `add_index` to `:email_provider` because that's the column name. Also, for the the `where` clause, I changed

```
'email_provider' -> 'sparkpost' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.sparkpost.com'
```

to

```
email_provider -> 'email_provider' -> 'sparkpost' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.sparkpost.com'
```

because the `->` operator expects it left argument to be a json(b) value, but you provided a string. So e.g. `email_provider -> 'email_provider'` extracts the value corresponding to `email_provider` from the column called `email_provider`. Note that this last line can be written more compactly as:

```
email_provider #>> '{email_provider,sparkpost,smtp_host}' = 'www.sparkpost.com'
```

by using the `#>>` which extracts a "path" from a josn(b) object. So the `add_index` statement can be written as:

```
add_index :accounts, :email_provider, name:  "index_accounts_on_email_provider_kind", using: :gin, where: "(email_provider #>> '{email_provider,sparkpost,smtp_host}' = 'www.sparkpost.com') AND (email_provider -> '{email_povider,amazon ses,smtp_host}' = 'www.awses.com')"
```

For you second index, you should try something like:

```
where: " social_account -> 'social_account' @> '[{\"type\": \"facebook\"}]'::jsonb AND social_account -> 'social_account' @> '[{\"type\": \"twitter\"}]'::jsonb"
```

In this case, I did the same think with the column as in the first case. I also changed the right argument of `@>`, which has to be a jsonb value. So you must define it as a JSON string, which requires double quotes for strings (also notice that we have to escape them for ruby), and then I type cast that string to `jsonb` to get the desired type.

Comment: Thanks I will try this out and get back to you. But I will most likely place the index  on the **name column** even though the jsonb column is **email provider** because the query will be faster when  the index is on the **name column** and the **where query** is used to restrict our index to matches from the jsonb column. You can see that approach explained here: http://blog.heapanalytics.com/speeding-up-postgresql-queries-with-partial-indexes/.

Comment: Many thanks. I kept the index on the **name column**.  The only change was to remove **using: :gin** since the index is not directly on the jsonb column. So final code for one of the indexes looks like this: **add_index :accounts, :name, name:  "index_accounts_on_name_email_provider", where: "(email_provider -> 'email_provider' -> 'sparkpost' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.sparkpost.com') AND (email_provider -> 'email_povider' -> 'amazon ses' ->> 'smtp_host' = 'www.awses.com')"**, which creates a **btree  partial index** on the **name column** restricting our matches to attributes in the jsonb column.